# How to session variable work with IN clause using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, variables, session-variables

I want to know how session variables work with `IN` clause using MySQL.

I tried this myself but seriously not success.

Queries with session variables

```
SET @concat_var := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(player_id) FROM tableB where id = 1);
// result 88,89
SELECT @concat_var;
SELECT player_id FROM tableA WHERE player_id IN (@concat_var);
```

Query Output (*not accurate*)

```
player_id 
88
```

(*Result required*)

```
player_id 
88 
89
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FIND_IN_SET()` is the answer of this question

```
SET @concat_var := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(player_id) FROM tableB where id = 1);
SELECT @concat_var;
SELECT player_id FROM tableA WHERE FIND_IN_SET(player_id,@concat_var);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know , it is not possible (**edit**: Turns out @QueryMaster was able to show that it is actually possible, although using MySQL proprietary extensions) to do it the way you're trying to, because the value of `@concat_var` is actually a single string, so your last query is actually equivalent to `SELECT player_id FROM tableA WHERE player_id IN ('88,89')` (MySQL will forcefully cast `'88,89'` to a numeric context by by parsing the integer prefix of the string, hence `88`).

However it should be possible to do the following:

```
SELECT player_id
FROM tableA
WHERE player_id IN (
    SELECT player_id
    FROM tableB
    WHERE id = 1
)
```

Or the almost equivalent (might perform better, as it doesn't involve a subquery):

```
SELECT player_id
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB USING (player_id)
WHERE tableB.id = 1
```

Comment: @QueryMaster Very good point. I didn't know about it. It'd work, although it's not standard SQL (my solution is), and happens to be exactly what the OP asks for.

Answer (score 0):

`@concat_var` contains the string `'88,89'`.  Therefore:

```
SELECT player_id FROM tableA WHERE player_id IN (@concat_var);
```

is performing:

```
SELECT player_id FROM tableA WHERE player_id IN ('88,89');
```

Since `player_id` is an integer type, MySQL performs the query by [comparing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/type-conversion.html) `player_id` and the string as floating point numbers:

```
SELECT player_id FROM tableA WHERE player_id IN (88.0);
```

Hence this is why you see the incorrect result that you report.

You should instead use a join:

```
SELECT player_id FROM tableA JOIN tableB USING (player_id) WHERE tableB.id = 1;
```

Comment: What do you think about FIND_IN_SET()

Comment: @QueryMaster: You could use that here, but a join is more appropriate.